# Which nano fish for a big, colorful, community tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater

I'm planning to set up a big (150 x 65 x 50 cm) tank with lots of small colorful fish and shrimp.

- I want the tank to be heavily planted
- I want the tank to be very colorful
- I want to keep a few species of colorful shrimp
- I want to keep a few species of colorful fish
- I don't want the plants to be destroyed by the fish
- I don't want the shrimp to be eaten by the fish

I'm thinking about some small shrimp species that won't interbreed (form [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upPj0.jpg))
[image]

As for the fish, I was thinking about:

- Some nice species of a guppy (single species to avoid interbreeding)
- Neon tetra (*Paracheirodon innesi*)
- *Boraras brigittae*
- Hatchet fish, to fill up the surface
- Some *Pangio kuhlii*, to add variety to the bottom (not too many though, because they'll probably harass baby shrimps a bit)
- Maybe a single *Betta* male

This still feels not enough for a 400 l tank. What else do think I could throw in there?

Comment: maby change out the betta and replace with algae eaters and a couple of assasin snails they eat other snails and fish food and they multiply very slowly but they are small.

Comment: We recently got pentazona barbs for our community tank, and they're small, cute, nicely coloured.

Answer (score 2):

Shrimp and fish is not a really good idea. The explanation is simple, the problem is the "zoeas" (baby shrimp).

All small fish, like tetra neon, etc. can eat them so this is a problem for the reproduction of your shrimp as well.

**Some options can be:**

- Use only herbivorous fish, some examples can be [*Otocinclus affinis*](https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/otocinclus/), [*Stiphodon sp.*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/stiphodon-ornatus/), [*Corydoras pygmaeus*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/corydoras-pygmaeus/) or [*Gyrinocheilus aymonieri*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/gyrinocheilus-aymonieri/). These fish doesn't eat zoeas.
- Use rasboras or fish like [*Boraras brigittae*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/boraras-brigittae/) or [*Poecilia wingei*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/poecilia-wingei/), these fish can eat zoeas so you need to put plants in your tank to make refuges for your shrimp. Other examples:

  - [*Celestichthys margaritatus*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/celestichthys-margaritatus/)
  - [*Hemigrammus rodwayi*](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/hemigrammus-rodwayi/)
  - [Ember Tetra](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/hyphessobrycon-amandae/)
  - [Flame Tetra](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/hyphessobrycon-flammeus/)
  - [Crystal Red Tetra](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/hyphessobrycon-haraldschultzi/)
- You can try to put "big fish" in your tank, like [*Metynnis argenteus*](https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/silver-dollar-fish/), this is an herbivorous fish and is cool to see when it grows to its maximum size. They don't attack other fishes.
- Surface fish like [hatchet fish](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/gasteropelecus-sternicla/) can be a good option in this tank, because the shrimp are bottom dwellers of the tank. You have another great options here, just make a search and you can find some good candidates for the aquarium.

**Bad options:**

- Single [*Betta* male](https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/crowntail-betta/), this is a really aggressive and territorial fish so you will have problems with other fish in the tank and with the shrimps.
- [Pentazona barbs](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/species/puntigrus-tetrazona/) or other barbs are a big problem, because these guys grow to a significant size and you will lose all your shrimp if they find them.
- If you put [assassin snails](https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/assassin-snail/) without putting others snails, assassin snails will die because they eat other snails, so you would need to feed them with other snails. They can eat other animal-based foods, but with other snails you don't need to keep feeding them with other alimentation.
- Put fish with a large size, because you will have problem with other fish and with the shrimp.

Comment: In a heavily planted tank I would not fear the few baby shrimps eaten by the fish. Especially with moss. Also assassin snail eat more diversely than generally written. they will eat dead shrimp/fish and some plants matter. Personal experience with a 15gal tank and also from a 70g. Since his tank is even larger it should not be a problem

Comment: @Rémi After read about assasins snail, yes is true he can eat other things (not plants) but is more easy put him with other snails or for control plagues, cause others snails can do the job of garbage collector and are more easy to keep, because the shrimps can be attackeds by assasins snails. (http://aquariumbreeder.com/assassin-snails-in-shrimp-tank-do-assassin-snails-eat-shrimp/)

In the other hand, if you put a lot of predators in the tank you will make reduce the colony of shrimps, so you can't make a good selection of shrimps. Cause u cant control what specimens you are losing.

Answer (score 0):

Tetras and snails.

Small neon colored tetras swim in groups and would swim around the middle and at the bottom of your tank.

Snails, avoid mystery snails since they do breed. I would go for assassin snails, some of them dig into the rocks!

Hope my suggestion works out for your future colorful tank!